# Eclipse Android Dependencies error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

[libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slEdN.png)i have already add libraries in my android project but in java build path show android dependencies error[jar file missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvJjL.png)

Comment: BTW, why don't you use gradle build system?

Comment: it is old project in eclipse thats by i can use  eclipse and now i want to update project but i faced this problem

Comment: @bhupindersingh u can see the file path in the second image right are those libraries available in that location? Something like F:/androidworkspace1/.....

Comment: @bhupindersingh remove all those and add it freshly and try.

Comment: @bhupindersingh Why are u adding both libraries and jars?

Comment: i'll try what its remain same